# I don't know how to display formset in django

Tags: django

I don't know how to display formset individually.

I understand how to display all at once.
But I tried some model field names, but it didn't work.

```
#views
class UserEdit(generic.UpdateView):
    model = User
    form_class = forms.UserUpdateForm
    template_name = 'accounts/accounts_edit.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('accounts:edit')

    def get_object(self):
        return get_object_or_404(User, pk=self.request.user.user_id)
```

```
#forms
class ProfileUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = profile
        fields = ('first_name','last_name','birthday')

        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
            for field in self.fields.values():
                field.widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'

ProfileFormSet = inlineformset_factory(User,profile,form=ProfileUpdateForm,extra=0)

class UserUpdateForm(mixins.ModelFormWithFormSetMixin,forms.ModelForm):
    #Userモデルにprofileモデルを入れる
    formset_class = ProfileFormSet
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username','email',)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for field in self.fields.values():
            field.widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'
```

```
#template
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            {% csrf_token %}
                {{ form.username.label_tag }}
                {{ form.username }}
                {{ form.email.label_tag }}
                {{ form.email }}
                {{ form.formset }}

            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
```

I want to specify and display instead of the method of displaying at once with formset.

**Postscript**
Mixins are created for data verification and data storage.

I want to display the details of formset display in template.
However, I only know how to display it at once, like {{form.formset}}.
Ideally I want to display it individually like {{form.formset.first_name}}

```
#mixins
class ModelFormWithFormSetMixin:

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ModelFormWithFormSetMixin, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.formset = self.formset_class(

            instance=self.instance,

            data=self.data if self.is_bound else None,
        )

    def is_valid(self):
        return super(ModelFormWithFormSetMixin, self).is_valid() and self.formset.is_valid()

    def save(self, commit=True):
        saved_instance = super(ModelFormWithFormSetMixin, self).save(commit)
        self.formset.save(commit)
        return saved_instance
```

Comment: which part exactly isn't working? What is `ModelFormWithFormSetMixin`?

Comment: I added.
Even if {{form.formset.first_name}} is entered, it is not displayed.

Comment: A formset is a set of forms so you have to loop through them `{% for subform in form.formset%}{{subform.first_name}}{%endfor%}`

Comment: It's amazing.
I was able to do it safely.
Sincerely thank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A formset is a set of forms so you have to loop through them {% for subform in form.formset%}{{subform.first_name}}{%endfor%}
Dirkgroten told me in the comments.
Thank you.